# Push notification to android app through WordPress site

Tags: android, wordpress, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm in situation where I've a wordpress site and I'm building an android app and what i want is to send a notification to all users having that app.

The app is basically rendering that website into a webview.

Please anyone help me to achieve this by suggesting some standard ways/plugins/tutorials/libraries/anything will take me one step forward.

I'm new to wordpress!!

Comment: Hi Bro, I am facing the same situation now. how did you achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For push notifications you can use [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) which is very simple and have a full featured dashboard for sending notifications.

Also if you want to send notifications from your wordpress site, have a look of [this](https://www.delitestudio.com/product/push-notifications-for-wordpress-android-library/).